# MacVim: Opening webview or displaying tooltips like TextMate

Tags: vim, textmate, macvim

I am starting on VIM and trying to understand it a bit. I currently use TextMate for web development, so I can build nice commands which take my current document/selection and display as a web view very quickly or send some results through tooltips.

I believe it's more appropriate to refer this question to MacVim since it has access to GUI elements so sometimes it might be possible?

"[HTML Output for Commands](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/html-output-for-commands/)" is a good explanation.

So I would like to know if it's posibble to output commands to a HTML window just like TextMate?

Or would I have to create my own program that accepts STDIN and display it as an html output on a view?

The same for the tooltips?

I was hoping that as MacVim is has access to Cocoa library and GUI elements perhaps it could already have some feature like this?

Sorry if I am misunderstanding things here, I really feel that it would be a good idea to migrate but obviously I would like to keep the nice and quick tools that I use and not losing a good visual appeal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so I would like to know if its posibble to output commands to an html window just like TextMate?

You could have vim issue a command at the command-line which would tell a browser to open a file you're editing.

On a Mac, using either vim at the command-line or MacVim, if you were editing a file called "test.html" in the buffer and it was in your Desktop folder:

```
:!open ~/Desktop/test.html
```

will open, or re-open the file in the browser. So, when you make a change you issue that and the browser will come to the foreground with the latest version of the file. You could use the other options to "open" to specify which browser to use. And, you could easily add a key press to open the current file, which is "%" on the command line.

If you want to capture the output of a command in vim, there are a couple ways to do that. If you execute a command vim will capture its output in a temporary buffer for viewing.

```
:!ls
```

displays:

```
:!ls
Desktop         Downloads       Library         Music           Photo Tools     Public          VirtualBox VMs  bin
Documents       Editors         Movies          Music Tools     Pictures        Sites           Web Tools
```

You can also see what's in [Command - R like functionality in MacVim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3811572/128421) and [Vim - Displaying Code Output in a New Window á la Textmate?](https://superuser.com/questions/133886/vim-displaying-code-output-in-a-new-window-a-la-textmate).

I'm not sure what you mean by "tooltips". Usually that refers to pop-up text at the tip of your mouse offering context sensitive help. You can't send text through that, so your use of the word is confusing.

MacVim and vim do have snippet-like capability, plus are scriptable, can work on text that is the current selection, plus a whole lot more. It's important to understand that MacVim is a GUI layer on top of the regular vim editor, so there are somethings it won't do because vim's engine doesn't make it easy. That hasn't ever bothered me, because if I need a particular TextMate feature I'll fire it up, use that particular thing, then jump back if I feel like it. But, that's not too common a need for me.

You might want to look at some of the related threads here on SO, over on the right hand side of the page, plus look at some of vim's plugins like:

- [taglist.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273)
- [vimspell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=465)
- [matchit.zip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39)
- [align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294)
- [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697)
- [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)

I use the above ones all the time. The following ones I'd miss if I didn't have them.

- [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025)
- [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)
- [Rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567)

---

EDIT:

Capturing the temporary buffer to a new buffer in Vim is pretty easy:

```
:redir @a
:sil !ls -al
:redir end
:vnew
"agp
```

The second line `:sil !ls -al` could be any execution of a command. `:sil` tells Vim to not echo the output to the temporary buffer, instead capture it silently, which gets rid of the "Press any key" pause.

`:vnew` creates a vertical split with a new buffer in it. You could use `:tabnew` instead if you want a new tab.

`"agp` tells it to use buffer `@a` and paste the output into the current buffer and leave the cursor below the pasted text.

Comment: thanks, this was quite a thorough explanation. One thing tho, in texmate I don't really need to have a file saved, I could just send the contents of the current selection or the whole document as input for output as html, so this is quite cool for testing and very quick things. perhaps vim saves each new buffer somewhere so I could open that file in the browser even if I didn't saved it before? is it possible to get a unsaved file /tmp location and send that out to the `open` command?

Comment: vim saves a .swp file, but you don't want to mess with that. saving a temp file is not a big deal though. It's trivial to save it using `:w somefile` then later remove it using `:!rm %` or just save it in `/tmp` and let the machine clean it up later.

Comment: Thanks again @the-tin-man, I guess that it would be more difficult to pipe the data to a program perform some actions and then output as an html since that would need a physical file, or this would need to create a dummy file and work from there, then output a static file with the proper data on it. I think the easiest thing would be to create a program that would display a web view based on the stdin. But with your directions I could understand better how it works. cheers again

Comment: @ludicco, Vim has a `redir` command useful for capturing output that would normally go to a temporary window into a variable. From there you can open a new window and dump the output. I'll add a small sample and you can go from there.

Comment: wow, very powerful and useful too, I just tried and might be an excellent alternative to html output, thanks again and congrats for the 10K :)

Comment: That's what I like about vim. At first it looks really primitive because it doesn't have all the bells and whistles, but after using it a while the strengths and flexibility really shines through. The best thing is, whatever you put in your .vimrc and .gvimrc files should be able to work on other platforms too. I use the same settings file and .vim folder on all my machines and VMs so, basically, I have the same editor everywhere. I can't do that with TextMate.